# Cannot install therubyracer in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've searched many solutions already, unfortunately, none of them worked out.
Here's what I get when I run bundle install:

```
Installing therubyracer 0.12.2 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/louiecubero/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20151229-3880-cwrbql.rb extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lpthread... yes
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling constants.cc
make: g++: Command not found
make: *** [constants.o] Error 127

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /home/louiecubero/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/therubyracer-0.12.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/louiecubero/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0-static/therubyracer-0.12.2/gem_make.out
```

The ruby version that I use is:

```
ruby 2.2.4p230 (2015-12-16 revision 53155) [x86_64-linux]
```

And my rails version is: rails 4.2.5

Comment: You are missing the g++ compiler. `apt-get install build-essential`.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its complaining that you don't have g++ installed yet.

I think you need to first do a `sudo apt-get install g++`

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much! :)

Comment: This works.. Thanks for saving my time..